# Ambiguous column name

Tags: sql, select

I don't know what might be wrong with this:

Please help me :/

```
SELECT 
   Name, CourseID,  CourseName,  MeetingDays, MeetingTime, ProfID 
FROM  
   Course,  CourseSection,  Student
WHERE 
   Course.CourseID = CourseSection.CourseID
ORDER BY 
   Name, CourseName
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Use table aliases and proper `join` syntax.  That will fix your problem.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You should be glad there was an error message, otherwise this would return nonsense, there's no join-condition between `Student` and the other tables. `JOIN `-syntax would force an `ON-condition.

Answer (score 0):

Tthe column name `CourseID` is present in two tables. So to get it right, use `<tablename>.CourseID` like:

```
SELECT Name, Course.CourseID,  CourseName,  MeetingDays, MeetingTime, ProfID 

FROM  Course,  CourseSection,  Student

WHERE Course.CourseID = CourseSection.CourseID

ORDER BY Name, CourseName
```

Comment: ohh sorry i forget to mention the Column name CourseID is the one that its presented in two tables, and its the one getting me the error "Ambiguous column name".

Comment: Ohh my bad, I thought it's Ambiguous Column `Name`. So what are the tables with CourseID as a column

Comment: the tables with CourseID Are = CourseSection and Course.

Comment: Edited the answer, that should fix your problem